# saving odd numbers between two number in an array

Tags: java

Trying to save odd numbers between 2 numbers in an array

```
public class OddNumber {

    static int[] oddNumbers(int l, int r) {
        if (r <= l)
            return null;
        int size = ((r - l) / 2) + 1;
        int arr[] = new int[size];
        int p = 0;
        for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {

            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                arr[p] = i;
                p++;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Odd numbers between 2 & 9 are: " + oddNumbers(2, 9));
    }
}
```

It is always giving same junk value "Odd numbers between 2 & 9 are: [I@15db9742". I dont know what is the problem

Comment: That is because you are trying to print array itself (Which hold the memory location of first index in array). To print data inside it you need to iterate through each element or do something like `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(oddNumbers(2, 9)));`

Comment: Perfect. Very silly miss.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  int result[] = oddNumbers(2, 9);
  System.out.print("Odd numbers between 2 & 9 are: ");
  for(int j=0;j<result.length;j++) {
   System.out.print(result[j]+" "); 
  }
 }

Comment: Add it in your question not here. It is hard to read.

Comment: Thanks Man @Goion

Comment: @Goion It is not the memory location of the array, but its identity hashcode. Objects can be moved around in memory by the garbage collector, so using memory locations for hashcodes would not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {

    static int[] oddNumbers(int l, int r) {

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                list.add(i);                
            }
        }


        int arr[] = new int[list.size()];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i++) {
            arr[i]=list.get(i);
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[] = oddNumbers(2, 9);
        for(int i : arr) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Later Part was faulty, correct is

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int result[] = oddNumbers(2, 9);
  System.out.print("Odd numbers between 2 & 9 are: ");
  for(int j=0;j<result.length;j++) {
   System.out.print(result[j]+" "); 
  }
 }

Comment: I only wrote the solution Rajan ,   about system.out out  he must use printf to  random numbers.